# What are the lower and upper hearing limits of the human ear?

Tags: hearing, human-ear

I am looking for the loudness limits, expressed in decibels, for the human ear.

Google and Wikipedia is only giving me the frequency limit that the [human ear](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ear) can receive, but I cannot find mention about the decibel limits.

Related question on acoustic frequency: [why-do-humans-hear-better-between-2khz-and-5khz](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/26067/why-do-humans-hear-better-between-2khz-and-5khz)

Comment: Decibel limit for what? The lowest discernible sound? That depends on frequency, age of listener, etc. The level at which damage occurs? What kind of damage? The level at which deafness occurs? How quickly are you talking about? Seconds? Minutes? Instantaneously? Basically, please [edit] your question (don't respond in the comments) and clarify what exactly you're looking for. Otherwise, this question may be closed as "Too Broad" or "Unclear What You're Asking".

Comment: i am not asking in frequency limit, i want answer in decibels, db.

Comment: I edited your question to improve its clarity

Comment: ok why you removed word decibel in the question.

Comment: I didn't, just in the title as loudness is pretty much by definition expressed in dB. Also - write @AliceD before you ask for clarification to ping me

Comment: sorry, thank you, for making my question more clear

Answer (score 3):

**Short answer**
Hearing threshold is 0 dB SPL at 1 kHz, and pain threshold is around 125 dB SPL at that frequency.

**Background**
Loudness thresholds depend on acoustic frequency (pitch), as depicted in the following figure:

[image: Contours]
<sup>Loudness contours in human. Source: [Stanford Uni](http://adg.stanford.edu/aa241/noise/noise.html)</sup>

When expressed in dB sound pressure level (dB SPL) the threshold of pain is approximately 125 dB SPL. The lower bound peaks at a hearing threshold of about -5 dB SPL at 4 kHz (maximum sensitivity). Outside that frequency, hearing sensitivity declines (and threshold hence increases).

Note that dB SPL references to a sound pressure of 20 µPa = 2 × 10<sup>−5</sup> Pa. This sound pressure corresponds to the hearing threshold at 1 kHz and is hence defined as 0 dB SPL. ([Stanford Uni](http://adg.stanford.edu/aa241/noise/noise.html)).

**Further reading**
[Why do humans hear better between 2kHz and 5 kHz](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/26067/why-do-humans-hear-better-between-2khz-and-5khz)

Comment: but you haven't mentioned any number between this and this is the decibel limit for human ear.

Comment: I did, and it's in the graph. Now in the short answer as well.

Comment: @KlaytonThomas - since you are new here - if the answer is to your liking and sufficient please accept it by clicking the check button on the left and/or upvote it. If it is not what you were after, just let us know :)